# Android project not recognizing enums in library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, enums

I'm consuming a Java library that contains numerous classes and a few enums. I am using this library in an Android project in Android Studio. The classes work just fine, but Android Studio does not recognize the enums. I can't import them or use them in Java or Kotlin files. I've used these enums in a pure Java project in IntelliJ before.

When I look at the "External Dependencies" in Android Studio and find this library, the classes show as just the class name (e.g. `MyClass`), but these enums include `.class` (e.g. `MyEnum.class`). Not sure if that's a clue. When I click in, I see the enum file contents just fine.

Some of my Android project settings:

- compile SDK = 33
- min SDK = 21
- source/target compatibility Java 1.8

**Update**

I found `INFO` level log messages corresponding to these enum classes in the Android Studio logs.

I obfuscated the package name, but this is the error I'm seeing:

```
INFO - #c.i.p.i.c.ClassFileStubBuilder - /Users/justin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.group/library-name/1.0.2/c5afbe59580f0678d1133deafc1d3d786e039b4b/library-name-1.0.2.jar!/com/group/library-name/FlagValueType.class: /Users/justin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.group/library-name/1.0.2/c5afbe59580f0678d1133deafc1d3d786e039b4b/library-name-1.0.2.jar!/com/group/FlagValueType.class: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "text" is null
```

The error at the end is:

```
Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "text" is null
```

This error must be preventing Android Studio from parsing this file correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a bug in Android Studio. Upgrading to the current release candidate resolved the issue.